# send Json from Phonegap app to remote server

Tags: ajax, json, cordova

The app I am building is basically a lengthy form for users to fill out. I have tried all kinds of versions of the code below which I garnered from other stackoverflow discussions. But so far I am not succeeding. I am only receiving an empty string on the server.

Here is what I have so far:

```
var data = { record_date: '324235', name:'mk'};
        $.ajax({
            type       : "POST",
            url        : url,
            crossDomain: true,
            data       : JSON.stringify(data),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success    : function(response) {
                alert('Works!');
            },
            error      : function() {
                alert('Now working!');                  
            }
        });
```

and on the server I have:

```
$array = $_POST;
var_dump($array);
```

which just outputs

```
array(0) { }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried not using `JSON.stringify`

Comment: Yes, I have tried that - to no avail.

Comment: Have you `whitelisted` your domain to allow cross-domain request in your config.xml file? Also have you tried using a GET request ( e.g url:example.com/test/demo.php?name=myname&greet=hello) and try to get the variables `myname` and `greet` in your PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

```
var userName = "{'record_date': '324235', 'name':'mk'}";
var parsedUsername = JSON.parse(userName);

        $.ajax({
            type       : "GET",
            url        : url,
            crossDomain: true,
            data       : parsedUsername,
...
...
...
```

Send the JSON like above, i think it works fine!

Comment: When I do this I get an error "Unexpected token o " which according to what I found means "Your data is already an object. No need to parse it. The javascript interpreter has already parsed it for you." ( I have in the interim changed all the single quotes to double quotes - which did not help in solving the problems either).